# Is GUI a part of WinNT in Windwos Serial?

Tags: windows, user-interface, architecture, kernel, x11

After I study some Linux kernel and X11, I am wonder what the position of GUI component is in windows.
Does it stay a position like X Windows ? or Is it part of Windows Kernel in the Core of kernel (or something like that)?
Is Qt, GTK+ wrap the Native Win32 API when it compile on Windows Machine?
Sorry for my bad english!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

User32 is probably the most comparable to X11, the sub-component that implements windows.  Gdi32 is the traditional graphics layer.  DirectX is important, not just for games anymore but the underlying engine for WPF and DirectWrite.  WinRT is new.

No, these are all usermode components and are not in the kernel.  The video driver was once usermode as well when NT still had micro-kernel ambitions but that didn't last long, perf was too poor.  Yes, Qt and GTK+ wrap user32.